# jQuery AJAX request failing in IE

Tags: json, internet-explorer, jquery

The following AJAX call is failing in IE.

```
$.ajax({
    url:"{{SITE_URL}}/content/twitter.json",
    dataType:"json",
    error:function(xhr, status, errorThrown) {
        alert(errorThrown+'\n'+status+'\n'+xhr.statusText);
    },
    success:function(json) {
               ...Snip...
    }
});
```

The error function returns

```
Undefined
parsererror
OK
```

No request is made to the server so I don't think its a problem with the JSON.

**Fixed, See #1351389**

Comment: It's working on other browsers?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Fixed, I changed the content-type from `application/json; charset=utf8` to just plain `application/json`.
I hate IE :)

Also to avoid IE super-caching try this:

```
var d = new Date();
$.ajax({
        url:"{{SITE_URL}}/content/twitter.json?_="+d.getTime(), 
...Snip...
```

That way each request is a new url for IE to get :D

Comment: God, am I glad I found this answer. This thing has cost me days of my life that Microsoft won't give me back. Just to reiterate: I effing hate IE, too.

Comment: Dear IE, I hate you.
Dear @Sam, I love you.

Comment: Also possible with jQuery.Ajax option "cache".

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#options

If set to false, it will force requested pages not to be cached by the browser. Setting cache to false also appends a query string parameter, "_=[TIMESTAMP]", to the URL.

Comment: why set content-type just to `application/json`. is work? can you explain this..?

Comment: Ie was getting hung up on the charset declaration

Comment: Thx for a solution! +1 for all IE haters

Comment: Sam, I don't know who you are, but I think I love you. I spent over a day trying to figure out why IE wouldn't parse the JSON. Nowhere on the internet does it say that IE fails to do so if you include the charset.

Comment: This also helps resolve every element on the page being selected if the AJAX call was aborted (not a success or error)

Answer (score 49):

For the caching problem why don't you simple use the `cache: false` parameter?

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: "yoururl",
    cache: false,
    ....
```

Comment: Cheers, solved it for me! I am curious as to why IE doesn't actually use the version that it caches...

Comment: Thanks, this saved me some confusion!  Was working fine with Firefox, but not in IE.

Answer (score 8):

is this a copy/paste?  the one thing that gets me all the time is leaving the last ',' in an object constructor.  that is, most browsers JS accept:

```
o = { a:1, b:2, c:3, };
```

but IE chokes on this because the comma after the last item.  change it to:

```
o = { a:1, b:2, c:3 };
```

and it works.

Comment: Men - you are a freak :) You saved me alot time. Note that this breaks only IE7 and below. From IE8 this isn't rise errors.

Answer (score 7):

In newer versions of internet explorer (IE7) it is necessary to write the next line before calling **$.ajax**, otherwise it would never call the function:

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); //this line before $.ajax!!!
$.ajax({
    //codes
    //codes
    //codes
});
```

Answer (score 4):

IE caches AJAX requests really aggressively (more so than Firefox, anyway). You need to set the Cache-Control headers in the response appropriately if this is not right for your site.

Comment: Good point, ive added ?_=1234 on the end of it and ie now request the page every time.
Still same problem though :(

Answer (score 2):

One major problem with statically generated JSON and IE are the leading "commas", for examples this throws an error in IE:

```
{
    "one":"hello",
    "two":"hi",
 }
```

Note the last comma.

Answer (score 0):

What is the {{SITE_URL}} chunk giving is about. Try looking at the code in view source code of the browser. If the {{SITE _URL}} chunk has a trailing slash and that would make the request url:

```
http://modomain.com//content/twitter.json
```

Which could creep IE out?

Comment: Well, any browser I know of woudl creep out about that... so this is no specific IE problem.

Answer (score 0):

IE: JSON not defined error resolved at

http://funkatron.com/site/comments/safely-parsing-json-in-javascript/

by using dataType: "json" and avoid parsing