# jQuery and ajaxSend not firing

Tags: jquery, ajax

I set the global `ajaxSend` callback as below in my `$(document).ready` function.

```
 // global AJAX methods
 $(document).ajaxSend(function(e, xhr, settings) {
  alert('here');
    });
```

However, I am never getting *here* even though I have several `$.ajax()` calls that run successfully after the document has loaded and on demand. Yet, *here* appears when I calling `$.post`.

Do global methods not call for `$.ajax` requests? I have not modified the `global` param, so they should.

I am fine using the `beforeSend`, but I need access to the url and other request data.

Any ideas would be appreciated as I have yet to find any gotchas from the docs.

Comment: If you use firebug, try turn it off - there is bug in some of the latest version, which prevent from firing these events.

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko, thanks. But still not gold.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

since it's a callback it doesn't need to be in `$(document).ready`. It can be a standard function.

---

set your callback function in your `$.ajax` calls and everything will be  fine.

[edit]

```
function ajaxSend(data)
{
alert('hello');
}

$.ajax({url: [url],
            type: 'POST',
            cache: false,
            data: oData,
            success: ajaxSend});
```

keeping it easy.. :)

Comment: Please elaborate or provide a code sample. Your suggestion is unclear.

Comment: Thanks for the elaboration. Please note that `ajaxSend` is a global callback method. Your recent post could be misleading. However, moving `$(document).ajaxSend(...)` outside `$(document).ready` per your original suggestion resolved the problem. Rookie mistake.

Comment: added some code. I hope I understood the OP's question right.

Comment: @Jason: http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSend/ you are right, sorry I thought it was a handmade function.

Comment: @Jason McCreary You should consider putting that comment as an answer because it is correct. This answer is not correct at all. Thanks!

Comment: @locrizak, I can't remember that far back :) However, I feel this answer solved my problem and the comment chain should make it clear.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using IE by the way? If so it caches ajax calls which are not posts.

see this link:
[jQuery AJAX request failing in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/425854/jquery-ajax-request-failing-in-ie)