# Cannot get jQuery's .ajax to work with Internet Explorer

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

This is my first post to stackoverflow. I have wrestled with this problem for several days. This AJAX request works in the latest versions of Chrome, Safari, Firefox, Opera, and [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/blastframe/ckcWk/). It does not work, however, in Internet Explorer. The success function will not fire and the complete function throws "error." As you can probably see from my request below, I've tried many techniques from different posts online, but none of them work.

It involves this jQuery's AJAX request.

```
$.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url:  "http://www.blastframe.com/gateway.php",
                data: {'action':'design'},
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                cache: false,
                beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", 
                    "application/json; charset=utf-8");
                },
                success: function(data)
                {
                    alert(data);
                },
                complete: function(req, textStatus)
                {
                    alert(textStatus);
                }
});
```

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Try using http://www.debugbar.com/ and check what happens after you sent the request.

Comment: Open IE's Developer console with F12 and watch for errors.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I am using Browserstack which has Companion.js installed, but does not pick up the error as it is the data returned from the ajax request.
http://blastframe.com/screenshots/companion.png

Comment: in the complete callback do `alert(req.responseText)` see what you get

Comment: I got 'undefined' from alert(req.responseText)

Comment: Have you read this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/q/1351389

Comment: Is `www.blastframe.com` your domain? Is the page on which this code is running located on the same domain?

Comment: @hyperslug, I did read that answer, which is, I believe, being addressed by my php file's header.

Comment: @ShadowWizard, blastframe.com is my domain. The Javascript and php are located in the same domain. That was an issue for Opera. Internet Explorer seems to not like something else. The Javascript is in a folder called 'test', the php file is one level up.

Comment: @ShadowWizard put me on the right track. I moved the .php file into the same directory and the ajax is now working. Thank you all! I'm a very happy man :-)

Comment: @KevinChristopher which IE Version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are using **complete** and **success** at the same time, I mean you are getting all statuses in **complete** anyway. Just use a switch in complete function to check whether it's success or an error.

Comment: It was just 'success'...I copied the complete function from another post in the hopes there would be some hint in it as to what was going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your Error could be fairly simple; how many times to you run these ajax requests? On one of my clients websites had an issue where IE was caching the javascript request so no matter how many times I try i still get the same result all the time; the solution? change from get to post as IE does not cache any post requests you can read more on this here in my [Ajax IE blog entry](http://jonmifsud.com/blog/ajax-ie-issues/)